# Field `insurance_primary_wage` does not exist

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

> Field `insurance_primary_wage` does not exist
>
> Error context: View `hr.contract.form` [view_id: 466, xml_id:
>   Egy_Salary_Insurance.hr_contract_view_form, model: hr.contract,
>   parent_id: n/a] None" while parsing
>   /home/whammam/Odoo12/extra/Egy_Salary_Insurance/views/hr_contract_insurance_views.xml:4,
>   near
>
> ```
>     <record id="hr_contract_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
>         <field name="name">hr.contract.form</field>
>         <field name="model">hr.contract</field>
>         <field name="arch" type="xml">
>             <form string="Current Contract">
>                 <sheet>
>                     <notebook>
>                         <page string="Salary Information" name="information">
>                             <group name="main_info">
>                                 <group name="salary_and_advantages" string="Monthly Advantages in Cash">
>                                     <label for="wage"/>
>                                     <div class="o_row" name="wage">
>                                         <field name="wage" nolabel="1"/>
>                                         <span>/ month</span>
>                                         <field name="insurance_primary_wage"/>
>                                         <field name="insurance_variable_wage"/>
>                                         <field name="total_insurance_wage"/>
>                                         <field name="insurance_subscription"/>
>                                     </div>
>                                     <field name="advantages" nolabel="1" placeholder="Advantages..." colspan="2" invisible="1"/>
>                                 </group>
>                             </group>
>                         </page>
>                     </notebook>
>                 </sheet>
>             </form>
>         </field>
>     </record>
> ```

Comment: There is no question here, or any code that produced the error?

Comment: i'm using odoo12 and i'm trying to customize contract for by impeded and computing insurance i can't solve this error

any body can help

Comment: you need to add info of your model `hr.contract`, I think have some problems there.

Answer (score 0):

Your model "hr.contract" is missing the "insurance_primary_wage" field.

The underlying cause of this issue is hard to pinpoint without any of your code. Looks to me like you are not importing the python file where you added these fields. Did you add an **init**.py files in "/home/whammam/Odoo12/extra/Egy_Salary_Insurance/models"?